# MySQL: "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" fails with fields terminated by 'μ'

Tags: php, mysql, csv, load-data-infile

I export a CSV-File in UTF-8 with Java. The char the fields are terminated by is the micro-symbol. As result MySQL imports the whole csv-line into the first table-field.

```
$sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/file.mysql'"
      . " INTO TABLE `test`"
      . " CHARACTER SET 'utf8'"
      . " FIELDS TERMINATED BY 'μ'"
      . " LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'";
```

The databases encoding is utf8. I tried `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $con);
  mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'", $con);
  mysql_set_charset('utf8', $con);`

before the load-data-query.

I tried also setting "|" as field-terminator. That works well.

//edit: It also works fine with SQL Server (mssql)

Comment: Sounds strange... Might it be that those two `μ` characters you mention are in fact two _different_ utf symbols that only look the same? That _would_ explain the behavior...

Comment: Did you tried open csv file using some utf8 editor like notepad++ and copy delimiter character from csv file to your variable? You can also try write some script to check if `μ` is really delimiter for example useing `fgetcsv()` or `explode()`. You also should check if your mysql database connection is set to `utf8`.

Comment: @arkascha How can I be sure to use the right symbol? @piotrekkr explode() works fine. I tried to switch the encoding everywhere to latin1/cp1252, where only one `μ` exists. Same problem.

Comment: The best test to check for ambigious utf sequences is to use a hexeditor. Open the file and check what numerical code(s) is (are) present at the position in question.

Comment: Rather than finding a hex editor, it is even easier to use "head -2 <file> | od -x". Does the last character on the line match the hex value for the UTF-8 codepoint for the mu character?